# How to align number and text dynamically

Tags: html, css

My content has listing and it shows like this

1   ABCD
2   ABCD
3   ABCD
4   ABCD

The number and the text can be increase to any extent like

100  ABCD
1000 ABCD
9999  ABCD

But when it comes to alignment, then the text move forward according to the number. But when compare the alignment between 1 and 9999, text are not aligned.

What i need is no matter what number it goes, the alignment of the text between 1 and 9999 should be same.
I am using `div` tag for number and title

My css for number is like this

```
number{width:auto;margin-right:4%;float:left;overflow:hidden}
title{width:85%;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;}
```

Please help.

Here is a working fiddle.

Comment: Please share the code snippet you have tried.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9wrv6fzg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a trivial answer but.. why not use a table?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>ABCD</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>99</td>
        <td>ABCD</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit**

Another option would be to use a [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving the number a fixed width if you know the maximum number of digits it'll have

```css
.number {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="number">1</span>
  <span class="title">ABCD</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="number">9</span>
  <span class="title">AB</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="number">99</span>
  <span class="title">ABC</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="number">999</span>
  <span class="title">A</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="number">9999</span>
  <span class="title">ABCD</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea about the digits.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/uzbw6anq/

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="rightAligned">
      <p>
        1234
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="leftAligned">
      <p>
        MyText
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="rightAligned">
      <p>
        123
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="leftAligned">
      <p>
        MyNewText
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

*{
  margin: 0;
}

.container{
  display: table;
}

.leftAligned, .rightAligned {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.leftAligned{
  width: 100px;
  text-align: left;
}

.rightAligned{
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use CSS Grid, I have removed the div with class `parent`, if that is needed, please let me know.

You can remove the `text-align: right` if you do not need it.

http://jsfiddle.net/qdmL6b9x/10/